# Operators depending on the same independent variable but commuting between them

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

As far as I understood in quantum mechanics two operators can commute even though they are not functionally independent, which means that they can depend on the same independent variable.

On the other hand I am not 100% sure about this, I've never seen two operators that depend on the same variable commuting between them. If my statement is correct, do you have any example of such operators?

Comment: What do you mean exactly here? Can you give examples?

Comment: Presumably OP means e.g. $[AA,AAA]=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you restrict attention to the finite-dimensional version of the problem, it is the other way around: two self-adjoint operators commute if and only if the are polynomials of the same operator.

To prove the "hard part" of this, a simple argument would be the following: two commuting self-adjoint operators share a common eigenbasis $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ for some set $I$, choose any family $(\lambda_i)_{i \in I}$ of pairwise distinct real numbers. Now take the two Lagrange polynomials that take the $\lambda_i$'s to the eigenvalues of the two operators and you're good.

The same should be true for self-adjoint operators on infinite-dimensional operators, but there are functional analytic problems to solve...